# quartz not honoring clusterCheckInInterval property in a spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have `quartz scheduler` integrated with spring application. `Triggers` on quartz works as expected. I want to increase clusterCheckInInterval property.

so here is what I have

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=30000
```

but I dont see this setting being honored. I see only the default value of 7500 being used in qrtz_scheduler_state table. Here is screenshot.

[image]

I am pretty sure the properties are loaded correctly since I have defined my dataSource connection in this property. I also flipped `isClustered` to `false` and I could see NO entries in qrtz_scheduler_state as expected.

I am using quartz 2.3.0 (Java).

Comment: based on http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html the default value is 15000. is it possible 7500 coming from somewhere else in your aaplication

Comment: apparently documentation is not updated. https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/JobStoreSupport.java#L130